# Attach a MS Sql Server DB with Hekaton In Memory Filestream folder

Tags: sql-server

Trying to attach a DB (came from 2014) to my 2016 instance. Problem is the DB also contains Hekaton InMemory functionality. I've copied everything over (data files, log files and Hekaton Filestream folders) and confirmed the service account has full access to the folder in uqestion (non Hekaton databases attached just fine), however I cannot for the life of me seem to convince Sql to allow me to attach a DB with a Hekaton filestream folder.

Instance is fully Filestream enabled and I can create a DB WITH a Hekaton filestream, however attaching seems to be a diffent story.

Here's my example code

```
Create Database MyDb On
( FileName = N'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserData\MyDb.mdf' ),
( FileName = N'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserLogs\MyDb_log.ldf' )

 For Attach
    With FileStream ( Directory_Name = 'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserData\MyDb-Hekaton' )
```

And here's the error I'm getting:

**Msg 33402, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
An invalid directory name 'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserData\MyDb-Hekaton' was specified. Use a valid Windows directory name.**

The GUI's no help as it has nothing there to help with attaching Hekton filestreams when the folder is in a different location. Permissions on my copied over filestream folder allow for both the service account and the NT Service\MSSQL$$SS user to have full control.

If I leave off the **With Filestream** part of the attach then Sql tries to open it from it's original location.

The folder has been triple confirmed as correct (copy and paste to\from Windows explorer etc) and I've also tried dropping the **\MyDb-Hekaton** from the passed folder and adding and removing closing \ symbol. No matter what I do though, Sql takes great offense.

***(NB: The 2014 to 2016 aspect is not the issue - I also get the same error if I detach and reattach a freshly created Hekaton DB on the same instance if I move the Hekaton folder).***

Comment: Just as a thought, try adding the trailing slash: `F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserData\MyDb-Hekaton\\`

Comment: Tried that - StackOverflow modified the part where I said that (the **** section). I'll modify the post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The folder is the filegroup itself. Something like this has worked in my case:

```
Create Database MyDb On
    ( FileName = 'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserData\MyDb.mdf' ),
    ( FileName = 'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserLogs\MyDb_log.ldf' )
    ( FileName = 'F:\MSSQL13.SS\MSSQL\UserData\MyDb-Hekaton' )
For Attach
```